# Load user spesific settings and site settings from db and pass data to view and controller

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-8

I was a codeigniter developer, recently i have moved to laravel.

In codeigniter I used to extend default `ci_controller` to `my_controller` and for all other controller I used to extend `my_controller`

in `my_controller` I load site Setting from database and user spesific settings.

store that to a variable so that i can access that from anywhere in view or controller

advantage of that was admin or user can update this settings from front end.

I can store user spesific settings like currency symbol, sms api key etc

Now I'm looking for an equivalent way in laravel.

throug which I can store user spesific settings and site settings in database, and retrieve that from any conteoller or blade file.

I know there are an env file but as far my understanding this is only good for storing site settings.
but what if i meed to store user spesific settings?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a config file:

```php
<?php

// file config/site.php

return [
    'foo' => 'bar'
]
```

Then you need to cache your setting, run this command in terminal `php artisan config:cache`

Then you can call your settings anywhere you want:

```
<?php

$foo = config('site.foo');
```

Comment: But I wanted to fetch settings based on different user role or different user id

Comment: On ``User`` model, you can make relation, for example ``settings``, and you can retrieve the setting wherever you want, like ``Auth::user()->settings``